# Buck converter and resistive wire

Tags: arduino, mosfet, buck, converter

I'd like to ask about my circuit.
It is a variable buck converter operated by an Arduino. At the end the 22 Ω resistor is resistive wire supposed to get hot because of the current.

One thing that bothers me is that when I apply 24 V something starts to buzz. I think it is the inductor, but I am not sure.

The circuit looks like this:

[image: circuit]

Simulator link: [Simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=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)

There is an NPN transistor controlled by the Arduino's 480 Hz PWM signal that drives the P-channel MOSFET.

Is it alright? I believe I picked all the component with adequate ratings but I might have missed something.

Comment: 100 Hz is much too low with a 100 uH inductor. You can see it in your own simulation. The inductor saturates and the current waveform looks like the same square wave as the voltage.

Comment: If you look at the [IRF9Z34N datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/IRF9Z34NPBF-International-Rectifier-datasheet-8776960.pdf) under Maximum Ratings, it shows \$V_{GS}\$ Gate-to-Source Voltage is +/-20V max.  Your 24V is exceeding that.  And the 20k resistors are much too large, leading to slow gate change, probably resulting in the FET heating up quickly.

Comment: @rdtsc The gate voltage limit is not exceeded, the gate receives 12V if the NPN is conducting. I agree, 2 kohm or less are needed here

Comment: You do need a capacitor to stabalize the voltage.  Frequency is low.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I apologize because I forgot to set proper frequency, I meant 480 Hz. I have a heatsink on the MOSFET because it was getting a little warm.  So the source of the buzz might be the MOSFET? I'll lower the resistors to 2kohm.

Comment: When I added 20uF capacitor to the output the current started to spike to 10A but my inductor can only withstand 3A so I should have much higher frequency and/or more than 100uH inductor

Comment: 480 Hz is still orders of magnitude too low. Why do you need a buck converter in the first place? I sense an XY problem.

Comment: I want to control the voltage that goes through the resistive wire (at the simulator its the resistor with 22 Ohm) , adjust it based on its surrounding temperature. And also I wanted to try to make a buck converter controlled with an arduino as a diy project.

Comment: I see that I should use Arduino's fast PWM that can run on much faster frequencies.

Comment: So you want to control the temperature, not voltage? A prime example of XY problem. What you need is on-off control with a temperature sensor and a comparator with hysteresis.

Comment: Can you provide any example of what you're suggesting ? I will be glad for that. I was thinking about setting the voltage for the resistive wire with resistance around 20 Ohm so it could get warm to like 60°C. I was thinking about controlling voltage for that manner and also like I said I wanted to try to build variable buck converter. I will appreciate any examples or study materials for what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you propose simulates as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKVkgS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltage waveforms]
[image: Load current waveform]

The load current looks OK, although the ripple is a bit high compared to the average current. L1's value should be doubled or tripled to get this ripple smaller, and thus also reduce EMI.

The gate voltage on M1 doesn't swing very fast, due to the time constant of the gate capacitance with R3. The mosfet will be running hot. A push-pull driver can be used instead, to reduce the mosfet dissipation.

The circuit below adds a Schottky clamp for Q1, to prevent it from saturating, and adds a push-pull buffer stage Q2-Q3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE2GdW.png)</sup>

Note the faster gate switching - about 200ns rise/fall time:

[image: Voltage waveforms]

Since L1 is doubled, the ripple current is halved:

[image: Load current waveform]

The rise times are further reduced when the push-pull stage is doubled:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5YeWw.png)</sup>

[image: Voltage waveforms]

Comment: Thank you good sir! Although I'd like to ask a "noob" question. How do you figure out the right components? I know that every MOSFET and Transistor have a datasheet but there are so many of them it's hard to find the right one. I try to learn as much as I can from any study material I can find but there is not mentioned anywhere how to select the right one.  I believe I almost understand how to choose even tho I picked a little too high values. Like R1 limits the current for Q1 and with hBeta makes current for the upper half and R2 and R3 voltage divider for Q2 and Q3 etc.

Comment: The only MOSFET specs that matter here is the DS voltage and current. That's because of the 22ohm series resistance in series with the heater: the series resistor already wastes power, so if the mosfet has loss due to RDS(on) channel resistance it doesn't matter much. Switching speed matters to maintain linearity of PWM. R1-R2 is there not to over-saturate Q1, with D1. The other resistors are "ballparks". I observed the waveforms and adjusted them. R3-R4 ratio is selected to get the desired gate voltage range - mainly to limit it, as 24V is too much.

Comment: Also I'd like to thank you for these eamples. I haven't come across push-pull output yet so I have some catching up to do.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing arduino to fast PWM with

```
    TCCR2B = 0b00000001; // x1
    TCCR2A = 0b00000011; // fast pwm
```

Now it is operating with frequencies around 62 kHz. I also changed the resistors to 1 kohm so nothing is vibrating or getting hot except the part that I want to get hot.

Here is a picture of the schematics:
[image: Circuit]
And here is a link to the simulation:
[Simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjOB0CcCsDMYBMsCmBaaIAstIHYxttD4kA2ADmgAYtt4RYdG10wwAoAJxHUpogk2QYOGjwNKT3D5yQ2PPEL5gsFJozslFbKWKQajZwA24coPhUhIkFZ2jIGutFdv3Hw5EopitWMKu2EgohpwAZnq6YHJ2SJaMSFDBlLCEKeScAOY4OiHYueDQSaKcAO42YgbKZKUVNfFFSbVhFWAWcWod9mG8NdbK2O2GQkjZlTjDg9ojmgBKfAIT7MQTEEnkKFJCkMxIu7MwnAAuI4N5towQ6EjwMB6U%20HA7Ig-4lGT4t2w66oIAJqhwgBDACuJmOnAAbnYaAUUEpbAjZjgxAUJDRduN4HDdD1kaUcu1BEN5MScDNSv9zCThuT8eAAHJpDicAAeIEoBTIVxmZHkBSIIAAknMAGLQABa8GwjPZIHwQkoEGqXJw4HhjPgtHg8oo8NuSryFHVQuEADVOCJGC14AEcOQCgwSiBoAB9R1umhu17ukRusCQchu9hupBu926jnsWBiZV8Z5INWCgqbXYAHQAzgBrAASAC9OEA)